# Make Espeak read the words from picture on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, python, espeak

I m working on a project that helps visually impaired people to listen to the writings on the printed paper. I have dealed with the part of converting printed text picture into pdf file with digital writing. Now I want espeak to access that writing and read it loud using python. can someone guide ?

Comment: You might want to first read - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 2):

A very simple image-to-voice conversion can be done from the command line by piping the output of [**tesseract-ocr**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/tesseract-ocr) [image: Install tesseract-ocr] to espeak. This can be done without further coding or conversions directly from an image source:

```
tesseract image.png stdout | espeak
```